# caught the following error during render TypeError: Zt.jsxDEV is not a function

Tags: typescript

I have a public component called `rd-component`, when  I used the Pay component which was contains in the `rd-component` in `main.tsx` like this:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client'
import './index.css'
import { Pay } from 'rd-component'

const payComplete = () => {

}

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Pay payFormText="formText"
                        price="2.00"
                        onPayComplete={payComplete}
                        payProvider="Alipay"></Pay>
  </React.StrictMode>,
)
```

show error in dev tools:

```
act-dom.production.min.js:189 TypeError: J.jsxDEV is not a function
    at dy (Pay.tsx:36:7)
    at Xh (react-dom.production.min.js:167:137)
    at Wk (react-dom.production.min.js:290:337)
    at Vk (react-dom.production.min.js:280:389)
    at Uk (react-dom.production.min.js:280:320)
    at Jk (react-dom.production.min.js:280:180)
    at Ok (react-dom.production.min.js:271:88)
    at Hk (react-dom.production.min.js:268:429)
    at J (scheduler.production.min.js:13:203)
    at MessagePort.R (scheduler.production.min.js:14:128)
Mi @ react-dom.production.min.js:189
Oi.c.callback @ react-dom.production.min.js:189
ih @ react-dom.production.min.js:144
lk @ react-dom.production.min.js:262
jk @ react-dom.production.min.js:260
ik @ react-dom.production.min.js:259
Xk @ react-dom.production.min.js:283
Qk @ react-dom.production.min.js:281
Hk @ react-dom.production.min.js:269
J @ scheduler.production.min.js:13
R @ scheduler.production.min.js:14
Show 11 more frames
react-dom.production.min.js:283 Uncaught TypeError: J.jsxDEV is not a function
    at dy (Pay.tsx:36:7)
    at Xh (react-dom.production.min.js:167:137)
    at Wk (react-dom.production.min.js:290:337)
    at Vk (react-dom.production.min.js:280:389)
    at Uk (react-dom.production.min.js:280:320)
    at Jk (react-dom.production.min.js:280:180)
    at Ok (react-dom.production.min.js:271:88)
    at Hk (react-dom.production.min.js:268:429)
    at J (scheduler.production.min.js:13:203)
    at MessagePort.R (scheduler.production.min.js:14:128)
d
```

reproduce the issue, first create the demo app using this command:

```
npm create vite@latest demo-web -- --template react-ts
```

then replace the `package.json` like this(add the dependencies and change the environment export NODE_ENV=production):

```
{
  "name": "demo-web",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "export NODE_ENV=production && vite",
    "build": "tsc && vite build",
    "lint": "eslint src --ext ts,tsx --report-unused-disable-directives --max-warnings 0",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@fingerprintjs/fingerprintjs": "^3.4.1",
    "rd-component": "^0.1.48",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.0.28",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.11",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.57.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.57.1",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint": "^8.38.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.3.4",
    "typescript": "^5.0.2",
    "vite": "^4.3.2"
  }
}
```

after install all dependencies, just run `pnpm run dev`, the error will be reproduce. why did this happen? what should I do to fixed this issue? do not forget to add the Pay component in the `main.tsx` file.